# Why all the functions don't work at all?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, strcmp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char passage[5000][20];
int wordnum;

char *getword(int x);

void readTextFile() {
    FILE *fp;
    //char buffer;

    fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");

    int i=1,j=1;
    while (fscanf(fp,"%c", &passage[i][j]) != EOF){
        if (passage[i][j] == '.' || passage[i][j] == ',' || passage[i][j] == '!' || passage[i][j] == '?' || passage[i][j] == ' '|| passage[i][j] == ';'){
            i++;
            j=1;
        }else{
            j++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    wordnum = i;
}

int main(){
    readTextFile();
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<20;i++){
        char *word = getword(i);
        if (strlen(word)<= 0)
            break;

        printf("%d\n", strcmp(word,"am"));
        printf("word[%d]=%s", i, word);
        printf("length = %i \n\n", strlen(word));
    }




}

char *getword(int i){
    static char s[20];
    int j=0;
    while (passage[i][j] != '\0'){
        s[j]=passage[i][j];
        j++;
    }
    s[j]='\0';
    return s;
}
```

I have written this program to read a passage from text file and then put the whole passage into 2d array for processing. The function I am working with is to get any word from the 2d array by the first index of it, then compare the word with some certain words and return the results.

But this program doesn't present anything, I didn't spot out anything wrong though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You need to be far more specific about the current behavior, what you have done to test it, how you have debugged it, etc.

Comment: The solution to this problem is really to learn to use a debugger.  If your approach to debugging it to post a question, developing anything is going to take you a very long time.

Comment: indexes in C start with 0, not 1 and continue to (number of items in array -1)

Comment: the function to read the text from the file is making the assumption that every word will be LESS THAN 20 characters,  that same function is failing to terminate the string arrays with a '\0' char (which might not be necessary as the array is declared in the file global space.

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 1):

because of this statement:

```
int i=1,j=1;
```

the first word will be all '\0' and all following words will have the first char be '\0'.

That is why nothing is being printed.

Note: this statement:

```
j=1;
```

should be:

```
j = 0;
```

because, as mentioned elsewhere in the comments, an array index in C starts with 0, not 1

Answer (score 0):

likely these lines:

```
int i=1,j=1;
while (fscanf(fp,"%c", &passage[i][j]) != EOF){
```

are the source of your immediate woe; your only call to getword has an i of zero, finding an empty (use before set) passage.
Should there be a ‘code review’ section on stack overflow?